# multiple regex matches for repeating blocks of multiple lines

Tags: objective-c, regex

**update 0**

I added the code with `for (... match in)` below.

**update 0**

My source text repeats approximately every 40 lines. Below I show 8 lines for each of 2 repetitions below. [The full data set is here](http://www.atlantaduplicatebridgeclub.com/scorepost/2013/01/20130126ana.pbn). I need from the "[Board]" line the one or two digits between the quotes; from the "[Dealer]" line I need the single letter between the quotes.

```
[Board "1"]
[Dealer "N"]
[Vulnerable "None"]
[Deal "N:Q952.652.KJT4.95 T.KQT84.A865.J73 K8763.A7.Q.KQT84 AJ4.J93.9732.A62"]
[Scoring ""]
[Declarer ""]
[Contract ""]

[Board "2"]
[Dealer "E"]
[Vulnerable "NS"]
[Deal "E:K8542.3.4.AT7532 J76.K7.AT85.KQJ8 QT3.AJ84.KJ963.4 A9.QT9652.Q72.96"]
[Scoring ""]
[Declarer ""]
[Contract ""]
```

The following regex sort of works, but only picks up one match, not the 30+ matches in my text.

```
NSString *toMatch = @"\\[Board \"([0-9][0-9]?)\"\\].*\\[Dealer \"([NEWS])\"\\]";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:toMatch options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&error];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in [regex matchesInString:string options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])])
    {
        NSLog(@"Number of ranges in match: %u", match.numberOfRanges);
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < match.numberOfRanges; ++i)
        {
            NSRange matchedRange = [match rangeAtIndex: i];
            NSString* tstring = [string substringWithRange: matchedRange];
            NSLog(@"range %lu string: %@", (unsigned long)i, tstring);
        }
    }
```

I suspect the problem is in the linefeeds, but I don't know how to fix it and the options
. This is a continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674787/gobbledygook-from-regex-with-capture-group).

How do I fix the regex pattern to get the multiple matches?

(In addition, I need the following on the "[Deal]" line, but let's ignore that for now. I need four separate groups, the first after the ":" and before the space, the second and third are between spaces, and the last is everything after the last space and before the quote.)

Comment: How are you executing the regexp? Are you using `matchesInString:options:range:`? Also, change `.*` to `.*?`.

Comment: I added the code with `for (... match in)`.

Comment: @Amadan: Using the non-greedy pattern `.*?` seems to solve the problem, you should post an answer. (I was about to post an answer but then I saw that you had already mentioned this in your comment.)

Comment: I agree, `.*?` did the trick.

Comment: @MartinR: Haha, sorry, I didn't mean to comment-block you! Also, three hours later, dreamlax's answer is quite correct, no sense in adding noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the problem in your pattern is that you have `.*` *and* you have chosen `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators`, so that `.*` will match *everything* until it reaches the last occurrence of `[Dealer` in the source text.

You can turn the `.*` into a “non-greedy” version by using `.*?`, alternatively you could avoid having the `.*` at all and replace it `\\n` (assuming your input is delimited with a single `\n`). Note that in order for the regular expression compiler to see `\` and `n` (which is the recognised escape sequence to match a linefeed character), you have to escape the `\` in the NSString, so you have to use `\\n`, i.e.:

```
NSString *toMatch = "\\[Board \"([0-9][0-9]?)\"\\]\\n\\[Dealer \"([NEWS])\"\\]";
```

If your source text  has Windows line endings you could use `\\r\\n` instead, etc.

Comment: I was able to make the `.*?` version work, but not the `//n` version. But I am good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (unescaped) pattern:

```
\[(\w+)\s+\"([^\"]*)\"\]
```

The first group is the tag name, and the second matched group is the contents between quotes whatever it is. You might be capable of capturing these values with `\1` and `\2` respectively in the code.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me get multiple matches. But it looks promising for other reasons.